# Jquery ajax call getting error in external url in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i getting error in jquery ajax call when given external url to get the result. the url was in mvc Dot net

```
 var url = "http://demo.bucesoft.com/BUCESFTDETAILS/insertrecrd";
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             datatype: "json",
             data: "{'obj':'" + Senddetails + "'}",
             type: "POST", // 'GET' or 'POST' ('GET' is the default)
             success: function (data) {
                 alert('sucess');
                 console.log(data);

             },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                 alert(err.Message);
             }
         });
```

in this i am getting error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demo.bucesoft.com/BUCESFTDETAILS/insertrecrd. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You must enable CORS to enable cross domain request.

To enable CORS support, add the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors) NuGet package to your project.

Add this code to your configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code config.EnableCors();
}
```

To enable cross-origin requests, add the [EnableCors] attribute to your Web API controller or controller method:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController 
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

---

In PHP you can allow by setting custom header like following.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
```

You can also enable for that particular site by defining name like

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomainname.com/");
```